# What is the function of this npn transistor?

Tags: led, mosfet, npn

I see that the R306 resistor is trying to limit current when the npn transistor is on. I am not sure what the resistance offered by the npn is but it looks like the current through the 47k resistor would depend on that. The collector voltage of the npn is then fed to the gate turning the MOSFET on.

How do I know that the voltage is sufficient to turn it on? I would need to know the voltage at the collector but for that I need to know the voltage at the base. But the base voltage depends on the MOSFET. How do I proceed finding the current and voltages in this circuit?

Overall what is this circuit trying to do?

The emitter of the npn is at ground.

The board is the NVIDIA jetson taden from https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/buy/jetson-tx2

It is connected to the supply rails of the ic(VDD_MOD).

[image]

Comment: This circuit looks like it's intended to be a linear constant-current LED driver.

Comment: "*Overall what is this circuit trying to do?*" Why don't you explain that. Where did the circuit come from? An LED driver, a battery charger, etc.? Why all the secrecy with the blackout and cropping the context? Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor I did not blank it out. It is the NVIDIA jetson carrier board and it was the way it came

Comment: OK. Add that info into your question then and explain what a NVIDIA 'jetson' (Jetson?) carrier board is and what this part of the carrier board is supposed to be doing. (When working towards a solution it always helps if you know the correct answer.) A link to the board datasheet might help too.

Comment: @Transistor The VDD_MOD is connected to the power rails of the IC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire circuit is a constant current sink for the LED.

The 19V through the 47K R306 turns the MOSFET on until the voltage across the E-B resistor R3?? reaches about 0.6 or 0.7V, at which point the NPN transistor turns on and limits the gate voltage by diverting some of the current through R306 to ground.

The constant current is thus about 0.7/R3?? and the LED can have up to almost 19V across it. The waste heat is dissipated by the MOSFET, the NPN transistor runs very cool.

Comment: I am a little confused about how to find the value of Vce which is across the npn. Initially MOSFET turns on increasing ib and increasing ic of the npn. But this causes the gate voltage of the mosfet to decrease. How do you find the voltage at which the Vce of the npn just produced enough voltage to turn of MOSFET on and controlling the mosfet current which controls ib?

Comment: The MOSFET (part number?) will turn 'on' with a relatively small voltage  from gate to source. For example, the it might be typically 2V with a variation from unit to unit and with temperature from 0.5V to 3V. As long as that is more than about 0.1V and less than 19V the collector voltage will settle at the voltage required to maintain the base-emitter voltage at about 0.7V. You don't really care much what it is. BJTs don't vary much in Vbe  so that's one reason why a small MOSFET is not used rather than a BJT- the level of the constant current is much more controlled.

Comment: When Vbe is 0.7 the transistor turns on. But why does the collector voltage try to maintain vbe at 0.7v? Shouldnt the collector voltage reach a point wheere the current throug the MOSFET which causes a vbe is equal to the ic that the npn draws from the voltage source?

Comment: Below about 0.7V the transistor is mostly 'off' so the MOSFET turns on. Above about 0.7 the transistor is mostly 'on' so the MOSFET turns off. It finds an equilibrium.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to fin this equlibrium point. The current rhough the npn controls how much current is going through the MOSFET. But current through the MOSFET controls how much current is drawn by the npn. How do i find when these 2 will be equal and why do you say for vbe 0.7v it will b equal?

Comment: The transistor Vbe will be about 0.7V when it is **partly on**. Above that and it's fully on, below that and it's fully off. That is just the way they work. Ignore the base current (a couple uA) and that means the source current must be 0.7/R.

Comment: How do you know the transisotr is going to be fully on? Initially MOSFET is on but after vbe begins to increase MOSFET begins to turn off. I am just wondering how you know it will be that vbe is 0.7v when there are 2 parameters cuntrolling the vbe voltage

Comment: 0.6 to 0.7V  is the typical Vbe  of all silicon bipolar transistors.